# Manually installing a program on Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, deb

I have installed Debian on my pc, but the problem is that at the moment I have no Internet connection to this pc. So, to install a program I have to manually downloaded from a pc with internet and then install it to the linux-debian computer.

The question is this: Is there a standard way to make the installation manually?
Note that when I connect a usb flash with the program I want to install(that is:   `cdparanoia_3.10.2+debian-10.1_i386.deb`) and I try opening it I get the message:

> Failed to execute child process “ar” no file or directory.

Comment: You don't want to manually open it and copy the files. You want to run ``apt`` so that it installs the local file without trying to fetch from repositories.

Comment: Did you use sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE to install the package?

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate on how to do this(I have the installation archive in a usb flash)?

Comment: @Victor          Do I just use this command in the terminal while I have the installation archive where?

Comment: I would recommend you first copy the file to your local hard drive and then execute that command in the directory where the file is located.

Comment: @Victor         I've just tried what you said. I get that the command wasn't found.

Comment: ? That's weird. Paste the command along with the output to fixee.org pastie.com or similar.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack Most installations will require multiple packages. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline Specifically check out `apt-offline`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha    Are you referring in general to the answers in that post or you are suggesting trying keryx?

Comment: @ConstantineBlack I don't have any specific recommendation, except that I think `apt-offline` might work for you. But I have never used it. I have no opinion about the GUI programs. See also https://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT

Comment: BTW, this is almost certainly a dupe. We seem to get this question quite regularly. Someone want to write up a canonical question?

Comment: @FaheemMitha     When I try using the apt-offline command, I also get "command wasn't found".

Comment: @ConstantineBlack you need to install it first. And, to be clear, you install that on  a machine with a net connection.

Comment: So, as long as I don't have an Internet connection there might be no solution to this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `.deb` file, you can install it from the command line with the [`dpkg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg) command. This is the single program that can install a deb package: all others (such as the APT family) are frontends that call `dpkg` under the hood.

```
dpkg -i cdparanoia_3.10.2+debian-10.1_i386.deb
```

You need to run this command as root, e.g. `su -c 'dpkg -i …'` or `sudo dpkg -i …`.

If your file manager complains about `ar`, that means it hasn't been configured to understand deb packages. Technically, deb packages are ar archives, but treating them as such isn't useful. Configure your package manager to associate `.deb` files with something that understands deb packages, such as `dpkg -i` (to install them, needs to be executed as root in a terminal), or `/usr/lib/mime/debian-view` (which needs to be executed in a terminal), or `gdebi-gtk` from the [gdebi](http://packages.debian.org/gdebi) package.

If you're going to do this often, [apt-offline](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) will help you. It isn't part of the default installation, so you'll need to install it manually (by downloading/USB/`dpkg`) before getting any benefit from it.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has been the most helpful. The commant dpkg works just fine. The problem is that after  installin apt-offline(versions 1.2 up to 1.6.1) I get from all-when executing them- the same error message:
""""kwstas@debian:~$ su -c 'apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig'
Password: 

Generating database of files that are needed for an update.

Generating database of files that are needed for an upgrade.
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
ERROR: FATAL: Something is wrong with the apt system."""". Any thoughts? Maybe post a different question? Thanks.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack I think this means that there are unresolved dependencies on your system: you've installed a package A that depends on a package B but B isn't installed. dpkg can let you get away with this but APT tools don't cope so well. Run `apt-get -f install` and see what it tells you. You may need to install additional packages before apt-offline starts working. Once you get it working, it'll take care of dependencies.

Comment: You are correct. The problem is there are a lot of dependencies. I 've tried installing some but now it seems there are even more. Is there a way to get rid of them or should I kill(sorry for the expression ) my entire afternoon installing manually all those packages?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was the most insightful and useful. Forget my last comment. I see that to fix these dependencies I need an internet connection. I will find a connection to fix them and then I will start using apt-offline. Thanks again.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack I don't know if `apt-offline` can help you if you start from a system with unresolved dependencies, check the documentation. If it doesn't help, you can use a manual approach to get the system to a good state. Run `dpkg --get-selections` on your offline machine to get a list of installed packages. On a machine connected to the internet, use `debootstrap` to start a minimal installation in a chroot, then `dpkg --set-selections` and `apt-get -f install` to install all the missing packages. Once you have a good installation, copy `/var/lib/apt/archives` to your offline machine.